# Counting occurrences in binary tree prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

I want to implement a code that would get the number of occurrences of a number in the whole tree, for example:

```
numberOfOccurrences(7, bt(6, bt(2, bt(1, nil, nil),
                                   bt(3, nil, nil)),
                             bt(8, bt(7, nil, nil),
                                   bt(9, nil, nil))), N).
N = 1;
```

how do i go about doing that ?

Comment: Im very new to prolog so this is what i got numberOfOccurrences(_,bt(),0).
numberOfOccurrences(E, bt(Root,LC,RC),N):-
    numberOfOccurrences(E,LC,Z),
    N is Z+1.

Comment: I rewrote my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to take the big problem, and break to down into multiple smaller problems. So first: Operating on trees is complicated, lists are much nicer to handle:

```
treeToList(Tree, List) :-
    % I use an accumulator, starting with an empty list.
    treeToList(Tree, [], List).

% The bottom is reached: The accumulated elements are the result.
treeToList(nil, Accu, Accu).

treeToList(bt(E, Left, Right), Accu0, List) :-
    Accu1 = [E|Accu0],              % prepend the accumulator with the current element
    treeToList(Left, Accu1, Accu2), % prepend elements of the left node
    treeToList(Right, Accu2, List). % prepend elements of the right node
```

```
?- treeToList(bt(6, bt(2, bt(1, nil, nil),
                          bt(3, nil, nil)),
                    bt(8, bt(7, nil, nil),
                          bt(9, nil, nil))), L).
L = [9, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2, 6].
```

Counting in a sorted list is much easier than counting an unsorted list. Prolog has a built-in [sort/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2) predicate for that.

```
?- sort([9, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2, 6], L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9].
```

You can count the number of adjacent values, and get the remaining, different values in one step:

```
removeFromFrontAndCount(_, [], [], N, N).

removeFromFrontAndCount(E, [F|Out], [F|Out], N, N) :-
    E \= F.

removeFromFrontAndCount(E, [E|In], Out, N0, N2) :-
    N1 is N0 + 1,
    removeFromFrontAndCount(E, In, Out, N1, N2).
```

```
?- removeFromFrontAndCount(1, [1,1,1,2,3,4], L, 0, N).
L = [2, 3, 4],
N = 3 ;
false.
```

Using that helper is predicate countAdjacent/3:

```
countAdjacent(List0, E, N) :-
    [E0|List1] = List0,
    removeFromFrontAndCount(E0, List1, List2, 1, CountE),
    (   % a semicolon is an either-or operator
        E = E0, N = CountE;
        countAdjacent(List2, E, N)
    ).
```

```
?- countAdjacent([1,1,1,2,2,3], E, N).
E = 1, N = 3 ;
E = 2, N = 2 ;
E = 3, N = 1 ;
false.
```

And to combine everything:

```
numberOfOccurrences(E, Tree, N) :-
    treeToList(Tree, List),
    sort(List, SortedList),
    countAdjacent(SortedList, E, N).
```

```
?- numberOfOccurrences(E, bt(6, bt(2, bt(1, nil, nil),
                                bt(3, nil, nil)),
                          bt(8, bt(7, nil, nil),
                                bt(9, nil, nil))), L).
E = 1, L = 1 ;
E = 2, L = 1 ;
E = 3, L = 1 ;
E = 6, L = 1 ;
E = 7, L = 1 ;
E = 8, L = 1 ;
E = 9, L = 1 ;
false.
```

Whole code:

```
numberOfOccurrences(E, Tree, N) :-
    treeToList(Tree, List),
    sort(List, SortedList),
    countAdjacent(SortedList, E, N).


treeToList(Tree, List) :-
    treeToList(Tree, [], List).

treeToList(nil, Accu, Accu).

treeToList(bt(E, Left, Right), Accu0, List) :-
    treeToList(Left, [E|Accu0], Accu1),
    treeToList(Right, Accu1, List).


countAdjacent(List0, E, N) :-
    [E0|List1] = List0,
    removeFromFrontAndCount(E0, List1, List2, 1, CountE),
    (
        E = E0, N = CountE;
        countAdjacent(List2, E, N)
    ).


removeFromFrontAndCount(_, [], [], N, N).

removeFromFrontAndCount(E, [F|Out], [F|Out], N, N) :-
    E \= F.

removeFromFrontAndCount(E, [E|In], Out, N0, N2) :-
    N1 is N0 + 1,
    removeFromFrontAndCount(E, In, Out, N1, N2).
```

Comment: following the "separation of concerns" design philosophy, `countAdjacent` could be further split into `rle/2` and `member/2`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried defining

```erlang
numberOfOccurrences(7, bt(6, bt(2, bt(1, nil, nil),
                                   bt(3, nil, nil)),
                             bt(8, bt(7, nil, nil),
                                   bt(9, nil, nil))), 1).
```

? Have you tried defining

```erlang
numberOfOccurrences(7, bt(6, bt(2, bt(1, nil, nil),
                                   bt(3, nil, nil)),
                             bt(8, bt(7, nil, nil),
                                   bt(9, nil, nil))), N) :- 
                   N = 1.
```

? Have you tried defining

```erlang
numberOfOccurrences(7, T, N) :-
                   T = bt(6, bt(2, bt(1, nil, nil),
                                   bt(3, nil, nil)),
                             bt(8, bt(7, nil, nil),
                                   bt(9, nil, nil))),
                   N = 1.
```

? Or maybe even

```erlang
numberOfOccurrences(7, T, N) :-
                   T = bt(6, TL, TR), 
                   TL =      bt(2, bt(1, nil, nil),    %%
                                   bt(3, nil, nil)),
                   TR =      bt(8, bt(7, nil, nil),    %%
                                   bt(9, nil, nil)),
                   N = 1.
```

? Have you also tried defining

```erlang
numberOfOccurrences(7, T, N) :-
                   T = bt(6, TL, TR), 
                   N1 = 0,                             %%
                   TL =      bt(2, bt(1, nil, nil),
                                   bt(3, nil, nil)),
                   NL = 0,                             %%
                   TR =      bt(8, bt(7, nil, nil),
                                   bt(9, nil, nil)),
                   NR = 1,                             %%
                   N is N1 + NL + NR.                  %%
```

? Must it not also be the case that

```erlang
numberOfOccurrences(7, T, N) :-
                   T = bt(6, TL, TR), 
                   N1 = 0,
                   TL =      bt(2, bt(1, nil, nil),
                                   bt(3, nil, nil)),
                   numberOfOccurrences(7, TL, NL),     %%
                   NL = 0,
                   TR =      bt(8, bt(7, nil, nil),
                                   bt(9, nil, nil)),
                   numberOfOccurrences(7, TR, NR),     %%
                   NR = 1,
                   N is N1 + NL + NR.
```

? And also just

```erlang
numberOfOccurrences(7, T, N) :-
                   T = bt(6, TL, TR), 
                   N1 = 0,
                                                       %%
                   numberOfOccurrences(7, TL, NL),
                                                       %%
                   numberOfOccurrences(7, TR, NR),
                                                       %%
                   N is N1 + NL + NR.
```

? Have you tried generalizing it further, removing the last artificially concrete values, replacing them with logic variables too,

```erlang
numberOfOccurrences( X, T, N) :-                       %%
                   T = bt( Y, TL, TR),                 %%
                   count_one_possible_occurrence( X, Y, N1),
                   numberOfOccurrences( X, TL, NL),    %%
                   numberOfOccurrences( X, TR, NR),    %%
                   N is N1 + NL + NR.
```

? Could you continue this line of thought?

Comment: Nice'nd new approach!

Comment: I'm waxing poetic on same old harp. :) I wanted to just comment initially, but it ran away from me. :)

Comment: @false and, [nothing new under the sun](http://conal.net/talks/compiling-gracefully.pdf). start from requirements, re-write it until it becomes a proper definition. (he called it "semantic derivation" in [his talk](https://haskell.love/conal-elliott/)). never knew about this work before. ---- (in case you weren't joking about "new", I've posted quite a few answers about this "generalization" code derivation technique recently in tag:prolog). it always starts with "start with what you already have / know" or something like that. :)

Comment: Your first steps are truly trivial (= belonging to the [trivium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivium) - the logic part of it) but for a beginner still insightful. Firstly that you take the (relatively complex) query and just paste it back as a program. I like to present the development of simple recursive predicates in a similar manner but starting from the base case. There is some hand-waving when you introduce the recursive goals (no semantic justification) - it could be elaborated. But then, such a presentation is always an appeal to the reader's intuitive side.

Comment: @false putting base case first is so *Lisp*. :) I like to focus first on the nature of the transformation/relation, on *what* is it we're doing, not on *when* must we stop doing it ("stop doing *what?*"), so, to deal with the non-base step first. corecursion is more appealing to me than recursion, it's more focused on the essence; recursion is more operational, concerns itself with termination, corecursion doesn't, only with productivity of the step. base case is like *an operational detail*. Prolog's TRMC ([tag:tailrecursion-modulo-cons]) made big impression on me when I first "got" it.

Comment: as the presentation technique, when you start from the base case you must already have an idea of what is it you're doing; I like to *discover* it, to come from a position of total ignorance and have the solution reveal itself on its own.

Comment: *"putting base case first is so Lisp"* Semi-agreement. Putting the base case first helps to find actual counter-examples. Is this so operational? I think not. As for revealing the solution you still need some formal justification which I fail to see for the moment.

Comment: having the base case first also helps to use the predicate in *generative* fashion, yes. with base case last it *will* get stuck in a loop. so we do need to move it first, but that's *after* it's written. I meant to *start writing it* from the general case, not that it must be so in the final definition, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: My approach is rather to run programs prior them being written. So start with a running but too general/too specialized program. Your first steps fit into this nicely...